# Raphael JS IE8 setSize issue

Tags: javascript, raphael

When on IE8 if the setSize method is causing strange behavior and will push the shapes of the screen.

Ie calling

```
clocks[i].paper.setSize('101','100')
```

Will eventually move the shapes off the screen to the right.

However

```
clocks[i].paper.setSize('100','100')
```

will behave as expected.

I believe this value '100','100' is set based on the starting settings.

http://codepen.io/ianw92/pen/YXPNbo/

To view the issue open this in IE8 and resize

Comment: Your code sample has many errors, but still runs.  It could be that IE8 handles those errors differently than other versions ... moving the blocks off screen.  Also, CSS works differently in different versions of IE.  That is another possible problem.  Suggest fixing your code as a first step.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the errors please?